# Creating an RPM package

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to create an RPM package that has dependency on R.

Question:
How to list that in the spec file i.e. install all the R-dependencies and then go through the latest commands ?

Also, to install the R, I need to run "rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm" to get the EPEL repo.

And then I need to install other R-specific packages on top of the R-installation.

Can somebody please help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fedora packaging page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:R?rd=Packaging/R), the package name is `R` (makes it easy to [find on the web](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=R), I suppose).

Your package's spec-file would list only the packages that it *directly* depends upon, e.g.,

```
Requires: R
```

If the version matters (probably not, at first), you would specify that on the `Requires` line.  The (given that you are setting up EPEL and whatever repositories are required for dependencies), `yum` is capable of *finding* which dependencies are needed.

The question as stated does not make it clear if you need a pointer to a tutorial on RPM packaging.  Besides the [Fedora wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Category:Package_Maintainers), the best source of information is [Maximum RPM](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/index.html).